# TFS 12 - Notification if work item is assigned to me for all users

Tags: email, notifications

Is it possible to configure a notification in TFS 12 that when a work item is assigned to a person that person gets an email?

And is it possible over all projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is possible. you need to set up team alert / personal alert in the Advanced Alerts Management Page.

Check this link for more details http://blogs.incyclesoftware.com/2012/08/setup-alerts-tfs-2012/

Comment: And is it possible over all projects or do I have to do this on every project.

Comment: I am afraid, you have to set up alert for each Project Team or Individual Team Member. There's no option to set up alert for all  Project Teams. you can also try this http://blog.mediawhole.com/2011/01/centralising-global-tfs.html I am not sure this one will work with TFS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the mediawhole solution cited by suresh2. I haven't tested it with TFS2012 but I suspect it would still work. Note it was written to meet a speicific set of requirements. Feel free to contact me if you're interested in a customised solution. http://blog.mediawhole.com/2011/01/centralising-global-tfs.html.

http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2012/08/setup-alerts-tfs-2012/ looks great too and may offer a better solution with less maintenance overhead.